# AngularJS - Invoking function from a dynamically created element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm developing a query builder in angularJS. I'm customizing [angular-query-builder](http://mfauveau.github.io/angular-query-builder/) .

The Code structure is (only the code relevant to the context is shown )

base.html

```
<query-builder group="filter.group"></query-builder>
```

querybuilder.html

```
<select ng-options="t.name as t.name for t in fields" ng-model="rule.field" execute-change="setValidation()" class="form-control input-sm"><option value="">--Select Filter--</option></select>

<select style="margin-left: 5px" ng-options="c.name as c.name for c in conditions" ng-model="rule.condition" class="form-control input-sm"></select>

<input type="text" ng-model="rule.data" class="form-control input-sm condition-inp" />
```

controller.js

```
$scope.setValidation = function () {
     console.log('Triggred')
 }
```

directive.js

```
.directive('queryBuilder', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            group: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'querybuilder.html',
        compile: function (element, attrs) {
            var content, directive;
            content = element.contents().remove();
            return function (scope, element, attrs) {

                element.on('change', function (e) {
                    scope.$apply(attrs.executeChange);
                });

            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

What I want is When selecting an item in the first drop down mentioned in `querybuilder.html` I need to add validation to the corresponding input box. 
ie, if the item selected is date, then the input box must be date picker and if it is phone number, then the input box should be integer.

I'm trying to do that using the `setValidation` function  in `controller.js` But that function is not getting triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping that this is used with a parent of a form as $setValidity is called on a named form input myFrom.nameOfInput.$setValidity.

If so you can pass the form to the directive or pass the validitor function as a parameter to the directive like scope right now takes only group let it take parentValidator as well and have that be a function in the parent controller that sets the validity.